# Dynamic font sizing with SCSS

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is it possible to set the font size relative to another element's font size using only SCSS and not JS?

For example, I want to get paragraph text 2 pixels smaller then input.

I've attempted something like this but it does not seem to work:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="This is input text">
<p>Text smaller then input</p>
```

**SCSS**

```
$isize: 16px;
$psize: $isizev - 2;

input {
  font-size: $isize;
}

p {
  font-size: $psize;
}
```

Comment: `$psize: $isizev - 2px;`?

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it on JSfiddle.net but it doen't seem to work. Or perhaps JSfiddle's SCSS rendering is broken... Is there another place it can be tested online?

Comment: yes, [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f4feed17dbc10208e9a2d26928a2b97e). You've also had a typo, `$isisev` instead of `$isize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also rely on the browser calc() function as per: https://caniuse.com/#search=calc()

```
$isize: 16px;
$psize: calc(#{$isize} - 2px);

input {
  font-size: $isize;
}

p {
  font-size: $psize;
}
```

Comment: Uh, I like this idea even more! What's the '#' for?

Comment: It allows using variable value inside the property value inside the calc() function. 
It is so-called interpolation as shown in example [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_). Without it, the variable wouldn't be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a function?

**SCSS**

```
@function ratioDimensions($factor:1, $base-dimension:16, $unit:px) {
  $calcSize: $base-dimension * $factor;
  @return #{$calcSize}#{$unit};
}
```

And then you can use:

**SCSS**

```
$isize: ratioDimensions(1);
$psize: ratioDimensions(1,16-2,px);

input {
  font-size: $isize;
}

p {
  font-size: $psize;
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting , but unfortunately I already have a font-size set for input in px...

Comment: Hmmm, pls have a look at the [link]https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/884fd97bc9df98f65114994e57901300
I assumed that there is only px unit used.